# Showing div on List Item Click JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu that allows users to view content depending on what's selected. The JQuery hides the `<div>` dependent on which link is selected. The link references a `<div>` ID.

HTML and CSS seems fine, but I can't get it to work properly with the JQuery. I've not really used JQuery in a few years, so some help as to where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated.

I've only put in working links and `<div>`s for four options as I was testing it, but obviously I'll sort that once I can figure out where the JQuery problems lie

```
    <div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">

            <li>
                <a href="#">Community Groups <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">

                    <li><a href="#tab1">1-Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2">Choir</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab3">Committee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab4">Creche</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Discovering Faith</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Friendship Club</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Kirk Klub</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Mainly Music</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Pastoral Care</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Social Committee</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Thursday Homegroup</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Welcome Team</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Young Women's Housegroup</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</div>

    <div>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
            <p>Tab #1 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #2 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #3 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum ri.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab4" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #4 content goes here!</p>
            <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {

}
  .tab-content {
        padding:15px;
        border-radius:3px;
        box-shadow:-1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
        background:#fff;
    }

        .tab {
            display:none;
        }

        .tab.active {
            display:block;
        }

.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}

/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#f1f1f1;
}

.menu {

    margin:0px;
}

.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:'Raleway';
}

.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:#3399ff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#666666;
}

.menu .arrow {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0%;
}

/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:23px;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 10px;
    display:inline-block;

}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {

}

/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}

.sub-menu {
    width:100%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:10px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#f1f1f1;
}

.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {

}
```

JQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(' .sub-menu a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('#tabs' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/t8pqn3e1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Before proceed further please take a deep look to [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

`jQuery('menu-wrap.menu.clearfix .sub-menu a')` is not valid.

should be

`jQuery('.menu-wrap .menu .clearfix .sub-menu a')`

More simpler

`jQuery('.menu-wrap .sub-menu a')`

or

`jQuery('.sub-menu a')`

AND

`jQuery('.tabs' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();`

need to be

`jQuery('#tabs' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();` as you're working with `id (eg. #tab1, #tab2 etc)`.

Comment: I've changed the selectors as described and updated my question, but I still appear to be having the same problems

Comment: @jmo please make a fiddle and paste the link here.

Comment: Suppose it would've helped if I'd added a JQuery library to my JSFiddle... other than the obvious change in the JQuery, had I done anything else wrong? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.menu-wrap .menu .clearfix .sub-menu a').on('click', function(e)  {
        console.log ("entered!!!");
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery(currentAttrValue).show();
        jQuery(currentAttrValue).siblings().hide();


        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

One thing to remember that jquery selectors follow the same rules as the css selectors. This should work.